# Date.parse yields different results on what seems to be the same date string

Tags: javascript

```js
const someDate = Date.parse("1/10/2020, 8:00 PM")
const someDateA = Date.parse("1/10/2020, 8:00 PM")
console.log('some date: ', someDate)
console.log('some date A: ', someDateA)
```

I have what seems to be two identical date strings, the first was typed and the second was **scraped** from some website. The typed one (someDate) produces the desired timestamp and the scrapped one (someDateA) yields NaN.

I can only assume one of the characters in someDateA is not what it seems. Am I correct and how to fix that?

```
const someDate = Date.parse("1/10/2020, 8:00 PM")
const someDateA = Date.parse("1/10/2020, 8:00 PM")
console.log('some date: ', someDate)
console.log('some date A: ', someDateA)
```

Comment: For the text you've posted, they both work. Can you paste in the scraped text into your question?

Comment: someDateA is giving NaN see the snippet

Comment: Yeah, it's weird character - you can see if you check on Dev tools `2020,&nbsp;8:00PM`

Comment: I can't seem to locate it, for the replace. guess I'll have to check one by one but I need a better method in case more 'weird chars' are planted in the dates.

Comment: @Light how did you check for that in the dev tools? I need to filter all of these from my text I guess

Comment: @S.Schenk for the record, this is a non-standard date format, so even without weird characters, you're not guaranteed for this to be parsed correctly.

Comment: @S.Schenk Give me a second and I'll write it out

Comment: Date parsing implementations differ by browser, so this isn't a reliable method regardless of weird characters. If your format is consistent, you'd be better off splitting the string into integers and passing them as separate arguments to `new Date(year, month, day, ...)`.

Comment: @Tyler Roper and others I'm thinking of using moment, but I'm not sure if I need that I'm parsing it in node anyways. Thinks for the tip might do just that.

Comment: Moment certainly provides more broader parsing and cross-browser consistency, though I haven't used it extensively enough to definitively say that it will or won't work with the date string you're using,

Comment: With Moment.js you can specify the the format of the String you're parsing, so fairly sure this would work fine for OP if that's what they wanted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check your question in DevTools (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> in Chrome), then select your Snippet text, you can see you have a non-breaking space in your second `Date.parse`

You can use `.replace(/\u00a0/g,' ');` to replace this non breaking space with the correct space